# css: right floated div goes to the next line when change its position

Tags: css, css-float, media-queries

When I change the position of div from fixed to relative in media rule, it goes to next line instead of staying floated  to the right. 
When I change the position to absolute, it overlays the footer. 
Could you please help me to fix this issue.

**jsfiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/EducateYourself/cz57tzb8/14/

**html:**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
aaa
</div>
<div id="right">
bbb
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
ccc
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#main {
    float: right;
    width: 798px;
    background-color:green;
}

#left {
    margin-top: 140px;
    float: left;
    width: 572px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#right {
    margin: 140px 0px 0px 572px;
    float: right;
    width: 226px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:red;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
  z-index:-1;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    #right {
        margin: 156px 0px 0px 572px;
        float: right;
        width: 226px;
        position: relative;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove right margin

```
#right {
    margin: 140px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    width: 226px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also add style for `#left` id in media query like this

```
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    #right {
        margin: 140px 0px 0px 0px;
        float: right;
        width: 226px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #left{
      float:left;

    }

}
```

Demo:https: https://jsfiddle.net/cz57tzb8/22/